# How to align text in sublime like the atom-alignment package?

Tags: javascript, sublime-text-3

I want to implement code formatting like this but don't know how to do this or how this is achieved.

```
var inherits     = require('inherits'),
    stream       = require('stream'),
    Stream       = stream.Stream ,
    events       = require('events'),
    _            = require('underscore')._,
    Connection   = require('../connection'),
    RecordStream = require('../record-stream'),
    CSV          = require('../csv'),
    Promise      = require('../promise');
```

As you can see ,there is equal spacing between left and right side of assignments

is there any lint/formatter tools that does this? I am currently using sublime text.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this doesn't answer your question, but are you sure that'd be called javascript?  I think those require lines look like nodejs but I think  what you've written are parts of nodejs and  parts that are unique to nodejs and won't work in regular/actual javascript.

Comment: and perhaps a slightly daft question, but what's wrong with the tab key for what you want to do?

Comment: thanks @barlop for replying, yes the above is nodejs, however I was looking for a tool similar to jsbeautifier that does this type of formatting, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a utility that does it, however not yet in sublime but in vscode.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steve8708.Align